# How to stop javascript filter function from iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js

my code is as follow

```
sortedProducts = sortedProducts.filter((product, i) => {
    if (i + 1 > limit) {
        return false;
    }
    return product.name.startsWith(search);
});
```

i want to stop iterating at the `index = limit`
so i can optimize my function because there is no need for items with `index > limit`
is there something similar to the word `break` in this case ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) runs the callback on every item:

> Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return a value that coerces to true to keep the element, or to false otherwise.

Therefore, instead of needlessly iterating over the rest of the items, you can  get the subarray first using [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
sortedProducts = sortedProducts
  .slice(0, limit)
  .filter(product => product.name.startsWith(search));
```

Another way to really "break" from the loop:

```
const arr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < sortedProducts.length; i++) {
  if (i + 1 > limit) {
    break;
  }
  if(sortedProducts[i].name.startsWith(search)) {
    arr.push(sortedProducts[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If want you want to use methods from `Array.prototype` and shortcut those, you might use `Array.prototype.some`

```
const collection = [];
sortedProducts
.some(function(product,i){
    if(this.length >= limit){
        return 1;
    }
    if(product.name.startsWith(search)){
        this.push(product)
    }
},collection)
```

I am passing an array as `this` to `some` method. You can do this with `map`, `forEach`, `every` etc. as well.

Instead of `this.length`, you can attach an arbitrary property like `this._iteration` and increment that etc. Other option is to slice the array like @Majed suggested, or just using good old loop and break from that.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to process your arrays as iterables. That way you will always iterate through values only once, while applying any number of operations that you want.

The example below is based on [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library:

```
import {pipe, filter, take} from 'iter-ops';

// define your sortedProducts, + search + limit here;

const result = pipe(
    sortedProducts,
    filter(product => product.name.startsWith(search)),
    take(limit)
);

console.log([...result]); // prints your found products
```